# How to ensure events don't get lost when using SignalR

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using SignarR for a Sales Supervisor Dashboard.  The dashboard shows the supervisor which saleperson is on a call, and allows him features in regards to this. This will be used by a group of approx 100 Salespeople and 10 different supervisors.

The back end is AspnetCore 3.1, the front end is the usual html/javascript.

Overall, SignalR is working just fine.  In a nutshell, the different actions that are taken by the CSR (like starting a call) are fired up to the hub, and then broadcast to the relevant Supervisor.  All of this work fine - **most of the time**.

The issue is that at times, events are lost.  For example, the event for starting a phone call never is received by the server, so it makes it appear that the Salesperson is not on a call, when in fact they are.

Or sometimes the Call End event will not fire, and then it appears they are on a call when they are not.  This happens in only 2-3% of the time, but it is enough to cause problems.

So I am looking at ways to improve the accuracy of the events to get it up to 100%.  I have had two ideas:

1. After the event is received by the server, send an "Acknowledgement" back to the client.  Then, on the client, if it does not receive the ack, fire the event again.
2. Fire a "stream" of events to the server.  So for example, if the user starts a phone call, send that event up to the server.  Then keep sending that same event to the server until the phone call is finished.  Then send the HungUp event repeatedly until some new event occurs.

Or should SignalR be capable of getting the events at 100%?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I have searched and all I could find was about the "withAutomaticReconnect" feature which I have now added.

Comment: Are you using Azure SignalR? And do you use cache like redis?

Comment: @Kiril1512, I am not use the Azure SignalR service, and I do not use a cache.  I am familiar with Azure SignalR, but not using a cache.

Answer (score 2):

I have not gotten any response on this yet, so I am going to note what I did that seems to be working so far.

1. set "withAutoReconnect()" when connecting.
2. Implemented the round trip acknowledgement.  So after the server recieves and event, it pushes an acknowledge back to the sending client.  If the client doesn't get this within two second, then it republishes the Event.

So far, so good.  I will update in later after it has baked for a while.

Comment: it's been awhile, but do you happen to remember how your solution panned out?

Comment: It's been a long time, and I haven't had problems since I implemented the above, so I would say it worked out well! I think #1 above was the key, I don't remember actually doing #2.